# What to use JSON file or SQL

Tags: mysql, json, ajax

I want to create a website that will have an ajax search. It will fetch the data or from a JSON file or from a database.I do not know which technology to use to store the data. JSON file or MySQL. Based on some quick research it is gonna be about 60000 entries. So the file size if i use JSON will be around 30- 50 MB and if use MySQL will have 60000 rows. What are the limitations of each technique and what are the benefits?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to comment since I need 50 rep. for commenting, so I will give it as an answer:

MySQL will be preferable for many reasons, not the least of which being you do not want your web server process to have write access to the filesystem (except for possibly logging) because that is an easy way to get exploited.

Also, the MySQL team has put a lot of engineering effort into things such as replication, concurrent access to data, ACID compliance, and data integrity.

Imagine if, for instance, you add a new field that is required in whatever data structure you are storing. If you store in JSON files, you will have to have some process that opens each file, adds the field, then saves it. Compare this to the difficulty of using ALTER TABLE with a DEFAULT value for the field. (A bit of a contrived example, but how many hacks do you want to leave in your codebase for dealing with old data?) so to be really blunt about, MySQL is a database while JSON is not, so the correct answer is MySQL, without hesitation. JSON is just a language, and barely even that. JSON was never designed to handle anything like concurrent connections or any sort of data manipulation, since its own function is to represent data, not to manage it.

So go with MySQL for storing the data. Then you should use some programming language to read that database, and send that information as JSON, rather than actually storing anything in JSON.

If you store the data in files, whether in JSON format or anything else, you will have all sorts of problems that people have stopped worrying about since databases started being used for the same thing. Size limitations, locks, name it. It's good enough when you have one user, but the moment you add more of them, you'll start solving so many problems that you would probably end up by writing an entire database engine just to handle the files for you, while all along you could have simply used an actual database. Do note! Don't take my word for granted, I am not an expert on this field, so let others post their answer and then judge by that. I think enough people here on stackoverflow have more experience then I do haha. These are NOT entirely my words, but I have taken out the parts that were true from what I knew and know and added some of my own knowledge :) Have a great time making your website

Comment: I dont know why you think this didnt deserve be an answer.

Comment: I don't know, my knowledge isn't that much compared to some on this website and to be honest: I wanted to keep it a bit shorter, compact you see... But since I was implementing it as an answer I thought: Why not just go all out and throw in all the knowledge I have / research I had done myself previously.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQl :you can select specific rows,or specific column using queries ,filter data based on a key,order alphabetically
downside:need a REST API to fetch data because it can't be accessed directly,you have to use php or python or whatever programming language for backend code.

for json file :benefits :no backend code directly accessed using GET http request.
downside:no filtering ,ordering or any queries,you have to do it manually.